# How do I save scores in an external text file from a rock, paper, scissors, game?

Tags: python

I am very new to python so I apologise for that. anyway I have programmed a simple rock, paper, scissors game where you play against a bot that randomly pulls "rock", "paper", or "scissors" from a list. The game (if you can call it that) works fine, However, I want to be able to save the game score to a text file, preferably called "score.txt", when the game ends, I have already tried doing this and it failed miserably, Heres the output from "score.txt"

```
Test |  | # theres meant to be a "Score" and a Win, Loss, and Tie in between
Test |  | # the | |, for e.g, Test | Win | 5 - Score
Test |  | #                   Test | Win | 10
Test |  | #                   Test | Loss | 5
```

and heres the code for the program I made:

```
import random
rps = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
score = "score"
score1 = 0
name = None
i = None
f = open("score.txt")

while not name:
    name = str(input("Enter a name: "))
for i in range(4):
    while not (i == "rock" or i == "paper" or i == "scissors"):
        i = str(input("Enter rock paper or scissors: "))
    choice_rps = random.choice(rps)
    print(choice_rps)

    if i == "rock" and choice_rps == "paper":
        result = "lost"
        print("You lost :(")
    elif i == "paper" and choice_rps == "rock":
        result = "won"
        print("You won!!!")
    elif i == "paper" and choice_rps == "scissors":
        result = "lost"
        print("You lost :(")
    elif i == "scissors" and choice_rps == "paper":
        result = "won"
        print("You won!!!!!!!")
    elif i == "scissors" and choice_rps == "rock":
        result = "lost"
        print("You lost :(")
    elif i == "rock" and choice_rps == "scissors":
        result = "won"
        print("You won!!!!!!")
    else:
        result = "tie"
        print("It's a tie")

        if result == "won":
            print("score + 5")
            score1 = score1 + 5
            f.write("\n" + name + " | Win | " + str(score1))
        elif result == "lost":
            print("score - 5")
            score1 = score1 - 5
            f.write("\n" + name + " | Loss | " + str(score1))
        elif result == "tie":
            print("score stays same")
            score1 = score1
```

Apologises if this seemms confusing to read. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
(I'm ten years old so more towards a simple answer would be appreciated :)

Comment: Read about `open`.

Comment: An ever-growing text file might not be a very sustainable solution. It works fine for a few hundred rounds but as the file keeps on growing, it will take longer and longer to load, which is at the very least annoying, but also prone to race conditions if you have several games in progress at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's three issues with your code:

1. `open()` takes in a second parameter that describes whether we want to read, write, or append to a file. In this case, we want to write to the file, so we should use `open('score.txt', 'w')` -- the `w` is for write.
2. You need to close your file after you're done writing to it using `f.close()`.
3. The code to actually write to the file needs to be shifted over one indent. Otherwise, if we win, the score handling code will never be executed (since it's under an `else` branch that handles ties).

Here's the code with all three fixes:

```py
import random
rps = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
score = "score"
score1 = 0
name = None
i = None
f = open("score.txt", "w")

while not name:
    name = str(input("Enter a name: "))

for i in range(4):
    while not (i == "rock" or i == "paper" or i == "scissors"):
        i = str(input("Enter rock paper or scissors: "))
    choice_rps = random.choice(rps)
    print(choice_rps)

    if i == "rock" and choice_rps == "paper":
        result = "lost"
        print("You lost :(")
    elif i == "paper" and choice_rps == "rock":
        result = "won"
        print("You won!!!")
    elif i == "paper" and choice_rps == "scissors":
        result = "lost"
        print("You lost :(")
    elif i == "scissors" and choice_rps == "paper":
        result = "won"
        print("You won!!!!!!!")
    elif i == "scissors" and choice_rps == "rock":
        result = "lost"
        print("You lost :(")
    elif i == "rock" and choice_rps == "scissors":
        result = "won"
        print("You won!!!!!!")
    else:
        result = "tie"
        print("It's a tie")

    if result == "won":
        print("score + 5")
        score1 = score1 + 5
        f.write("\n" + name + " | Win | " + str(score1))
    elif result == "lost":
        print("score - 5")
        score1 = score1 - 5
        f.write("\n" + name + " | Loss | " + str(score1))
    elif result == "tie":
        print("score stays same")
        score1 = score1

f.close()
```

Comment: thank you for the fast response, and it worked thanks

Comment: @moron if you are happy with a solution, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Edits in the code:
1- `with open("score.txt", "a") as f:` # not to use close func, "a" is to append new values, use "w" if you want to rewrite the whole file
2- indentation fixed
3- using string format allows you to print a dynamic string

here is a working version of your code:
import random

```
rps = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
score = "score"
score1 = 0
name = None
i = None
with open("score.txt", "a") as f: # not to use close func, "a" is to append new values, use "w" if you want to rewrite the whole file

    while not name:
        name = str(input("Enter a name: "))
    for i in range(4):
        while not (i == "rock" or i == "paper" or i == "scissors"):
            i = str(input("Enter rock paper or scissors: "))
        choice_rps = random.choice(rps)
        print(choice_rps)

        if i == "rock" and choice_rps == "paper":
            result = "lost"
            print("You lost :(")
        elif i == "paper" and choice_rps == "rock":
            result = "won"
            print("You won!!!")
        elif i == "paper" and choice_rps == "scissors":
            result = "lost"
            print("You lost :(")
        elif i == "scissors" and choice_rps == "paper":
            result = "won"
            print("You won!!!!!!!")
        elif i == "scissors" and choice_rps == "rock":
            result = "lost"
            print("You lost :(")
        elif i == "rock" and choice_rps == "scissors":
            result = "won"
            print("You won!!!!!!")
        else:
            result = "tie"
            print("It's a tie")

        if result == "won": #indentation fixed from here to the end 
            print("score + 5")
            score1 = score1 + 5
            f.write(f"{name} | Win | {str(score1)} \n")#using string format allows you to have a dynamic string
        elif result == "lost":
            print("score - 5")
            score1 = score1 - 5
            f.write(f"{name} | Lose | {str(score1)} \n")
        elif result == "tie":
            print("score stays same")
            score1 = score1
```

Comment: without an explanation on how you fixed or what was wrong this is pretty much useless.

Comment: I thought adding the fixes as comments in the code is enough